# AWS Memorydb create multiple databases in a single instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-memory-db

Earlier I was using Redis DB and in that, I have 8 databases set in the Redis conf file and I have a total of 8 databases named db0, db1, db2 ....db7.
recently I have created a new instance of memoryDB in AWS and in that redis config file i have set the database's value to 16 but I'm getting only db0 database rest are missing.
Can someone help how I can create the rest of the databases like db1 db2 to the same memory DB instance?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean missing? Do you get an error when you try to connect to one?

Comment: what i mean by missing is ideally it should have more dbs like earlier because in config it is declared but they are not there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon MemoryDB for Redis (and Amazon ElastiCache for Redis in cluster-mode-enabled configurations) support DB0 only.